# Path with special character not found

Tags: powershell, path

in PowerShell, I have a script which sets up a variable

```
$PATHX= "\\server\R&D\binary\"+$stringbinaryname
```

When I run a command

```
Copy-Item -path "$PATHX" -destination "$PATHY"
```

The PATHX gives an error of not found path.

I have tried using a local path, or mapping this virtual address to a drive K:\

Results are that in local path C:... Works, but the K:\ path says "drive not found".

Also tried to escape the & with `& with no result.

Any hotfix for this?

Comment: Generally, `-LiteralPath` is the better parameter to use if you want to ensure that PS doesn't interpret the value as a _wildcard_ expression. That said, that doesn't appear to be your problem. What happens if you pass the path to `Test-Path -LiteralPath`? Was your drive mapping really successful?

Comment: The mapping is entirely successful since I can see the new mapped drive and Access it.

Comment: I think you need to add more information to your question before anyone can help you. E.g., show the full paths you've tried (both source and destination), output from `Test-Path`, output from `Trace-Command -pshost -name parameterbinding { ... }`, ... Try to get as close as you can to providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

```
$PATHX = "\\server\R&D\binary\$stringbinaryname"
```

Alternatively you could use `Join-Path` like:

```
$PATHX = Join-Path \\server\R&D\binary $stringbinaryname
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think this builds exactly an equivalent string to the one which I am creating. The problema might be in the interpretation of this path string ... because without & seems to work.